# "Hot" Debug and Swap in Common LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

One of the features that are unique to Common Lisp that is frequently mentioned is that of the "hot" debug. That is, it is the ability to debug, edit and recompile the production code without stopping or taking the latter off line.

While I see this mentioned all the time, I have yet to see a tutorial on how to do it.

How does one do it in, say, Emacs? Are there some simple examples? Is the feature truly as magical as it seems?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I opened an issue in the CL Cookbook, with information from my answer. https://github.com/LispCookbook/cl-cookbook/issues/115

Comment: By the way, this CookBook looks really useful. I am certainly gonna peruse and maybe even contribute! Do you have any suggestion on the order in which it should be read?

Comment: I think you should read Data Structures indeed, the rest as your needs arise. And yes please contribute, there's room for it, and we should do it as we learn or nobody will do it. You can write something up, look at the issues, or fill one if something's missing, and there is (error handling,…). See you there !

Comment: By the way, should the articles in cookbook be kept strictly to Lisp or one can write about using certain tools (Emacs, particular web servers such as Clack, Caveman2, etc)?

Comment: Its goal is to "gettings things down" so yes, and yes absolutely because there are already stuff about Emacs (Editor Support -> Emacs), that needs to be freshened up, and we have an issue discussing web development !

Comment: *getting things done

Comment: I am new, but I shall try to contribute as I myself learn.

Answer (score 4):

The typical way to do this is to enable SWANK in the application that you want to debug. That way you can use `M-x slime-connect` from Emacs to connect to the running server. From there, you can do anything you can do with a normal SLIME session. You can even set up the way file names re resolved so that when you use `M-.` to jump to the source of a function, it will be opened on the remote machine using Tramp.

I think the reason you haven't seen a tutorial on it is because it's a natural thing to do, and there really isn't much of a difference between doing local debugging and working on a remote system.

There is a video of a lecture I did once where I demonstrated some of this, so there definitely are videos out there. However, I think linking to external videos is frowned upon on Stackoverflow.

Comment: oh… can you link to the video in a comment maybe ?

Comment: but but but… I know this video and I link to it and to [Potato](https://github.com/cicakhq/potato) quite often :)  (Potato: Slack-like built in CL and ClojureScript with a bunch of features) Glad to see you still around. This video is a bit longish though, it would be totally awesome if you had a shorter one or if you wrote about your workflow. We don't have a lot of showcase (and specially for web stuff).

Comment: That's a good point, and I agree that it's needed. Something like Emacs Rocks, but for CL. Have you thought about doing something like that?

Comment: I don't feel confident enough in CL for videos (…yet?). While learning I contribute documentation, specially in the CL Cookbook (90 commits already :) ). I'm trying out web scraping and other stuff of the ecosystem right now, first to learn but also to write a tutorial in the process. I might do a video. Or add plenty of gifs :)

Comment: Do you, per chance, know if it is possible to automate this hot swap? Suppose one knows that only a couple of files with source code changed. How would he deploy them to production in Lisp fashion? What is the analog of continuous deployment in Lisp? :)

Answer (score 3):

Some notes I took for myself. I largely agree we should have a tutorial out there. In the [CL Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/) ?

(**edit**: there's now a [more complete example here](https://lisp-journey.gitlab.io/web-dev/#connecting-to-a-remote-swank-server))

Reading http://readevalprint.tumblr.com/post/101841449553/its-alive-the-path-from-library-to-web-app

> Another option is hot swapping all the changes. For this purpose my hunchentoot server also starts a swank server like this:

```
(defun start-app (&optional (port 8080))
  (handler-case (swank:create-server :dont-close t)
    (error ()))
    …
```

> Swank is, of course, the server-side component of SLIME. It runs on a port that is not accessible remotely and can only be connected to locally or via SSH tunnel. I use the latter to connect SLIME on my PC to Swank running on my server, which allows me to apply various fixes without restarting, either from the REPL or by using C-c C-c to recompile some function.

#### Connect to a remote Slime server:

- Install a Common Lisp implementation on the server. (E.g. sbcl, clisp, etc...)
- Install quicklisp on the server.
- Load SWANK with `(ql:quickload :swank)`
- Start the server with `(swank:create-server)`. The default port is 4005. [On your local machine] Create a SSH tunnel with ssh -L4005:127.0.0.1:4005 [remote machine]
- Connect to the running remote swank server with `M-x slime-connect`.
- The host should be 127.0.0.1 and the port 4005.

(reading an old SO doc page, impossible to link to now).

Comment: Thank you. By the way, how does the C-c C-c work? I was trying to use it to recompile my web project locally as I was adding routes, but it kept bouncing me to the debugger where I could pick of roughly three choices.

Comment: On another note, if you have any suggestion for resources that will explain how do practical and useful stuff like this to a beginner, I would love to learn about them.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't say much about the C-c C-c without seeing your app and the errors… stay calm, and go step by step :) you may need to C-c C-c your asd definition and quickload your project. I learned a bunch with [malisper's blog serie on debugging](http://malisper.me/debugging-lisp-part-1-recompilation/) and [lispmethods](http://lispmethods.com/), and then I recommend to not miss the following resources: the [cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/), [Awesome CL](https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl) and [lisp-lang.org](http://lisp-lang.org/).